# same height for all the <li> list

Tags: css, list

I've created a list style for displaying some images and description text. However, when the list drop to another row, it wont follow the same height as the first row.

Anyway that can make the list align accordingly?

```
<ul>
<li><div class="dashed-box"></div>
<h3>title a</h3>
<h4>Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.</h4>
</li>

<li><div class="dashed-box"></div>
<h3>title b</h3>
<h4>Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus.</h4>
</li>

<li><div class="dashed-box"></div>
<h3>title c</h3>
<h4>Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu</h4>
</li>

<li><div class="dashed-box"></div>
<h3>title d</h3>
<h4>Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</h4>
</li>    

<li><div class="dashed-box"></div>
<h3>title e</h3>
<h4>Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi.</h4>
</li>  

<li><div class="dashed-box"></div>
<h3>title f</h3>
<h4> Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim.</h4>
</li>    

</ul>
```

Here's my example
http://jsfiddle.net/pdh8Lacd/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried maybe using calc, to calculate the width of the elements (so it's responsive), and say we want 4 elements per row, then we apply a nth-child selector to clear the results?

The changes I've done are:

```
li { float: left; width: calc((100% / 4) - 20px); margin: 20px 0;}
```

Instead of

```
li { float: left; width:250px; margin: 20px 0;}
```

And adding this line:

```
li:nth-child(4n + 1) { clear: both; }
```

You can check out the fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/pdh8Lacd/8/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this using [FlexBox](http://osvaldas.info/flexbox-based-responsive-equal-height-blocks-with-javascript-fallback)

```
.list{ display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and

```
.list__item { display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7z9358qm/)